# Remove a snap package on WSL Ubuntu

Tags: snap, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to remove a snap package and see the way to do so is `sudo snap remove <package>`. This fails as follows:

```
~ sudo snap remove zola
error: access denied (see 'snap help login')
```

Running snap on WSL is a bit problematic, and I had to run the script supplied in this thread for it to work: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=snap+ubuntu+wsl

```bash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -yqq daemonize dbus-user-session fontconfig sudo 
daemonize /usr/bin/unshare --fork --pid --mount-proc /lib/systemd/systemd --system-
unit=basic.target exec sudo nsenter -t $(pidof systemd) -a su - $LOGNAME
```

this was able to get snap to install packages but doesn't seem to be able to remove them.

When I try logging into my ubuntu one account, (`snap help login`, `sudo snap login <email>`), I get the error:

```
error: access denied (see 'snap help login')
```

Comment: I would say this is why snaps *don't* work on WSL - and a reason you should not bypass the limitations.  It's pretty clear that snaps don't work properly on WSL, which because you followed some random script to install and configure snaps, you've likely done something Not Supported Yet in WSL, meaning using snaps with WSL will lead to unexpected behavior like you're seeing here

Comment: Ok I see, I posted an answer here since other WSL users will undoubtedly stumble upon this same issue in the future

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because snaps are currently unsupported on WSL